# The out parameter must be assigned to before control leaves the current methods

Tags: c#

I'm very new C# and this is the first time I'm doing anything with a list, so this might be a very dumb question... I'm trying to read data from a file to a list that consists of `Tourist` objects. As I understand I need to assign something to `tourists` list before I add objects to it, but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
class Tourist
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public double Contributed { get; set; }

    public Tourist(string firstName, string lastName, double money)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Contributed = money * 0.25;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Tourist> tourists = new List<Tourist>();

        ReadData(out tourists);
    }

    static void ReadData(out List<Tourist> tourists)
    {
        const string Input = "..\\..\\Duomenys.txt";

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Input);
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string[] values = line.Split(';');
            string firstName = values[0];
            string lastName = values[1];
            double money = Double.Parse(values[2]);
            tourists.Add(new Tourist(firstName, lastName, money));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `out`-parameter. A method that is supposed to read data and return it should not be `void` but return `List<Tourist>`. However, an `out`-parameter must be initialized in the method itself, that's why the compiler complains. An `out`-parameter is like a contract between the method and the caller, it is guaranteed that the parameter is assigned and initialized in the method (well, the latter not really because you can assign `null`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By declaring a parameter as `out` you "promise" the caller (and the compiler) that your method *will set a value* to the variable provided as argument for that parameter.

Because you promise it, every path through your method *must* assign a value to this parameter.

Your method does *not* assign a value to `tourists`. This may actually lead to a `NullReferenceException` at `tourists.Add(...)` if the method gets called with a `null` reference.

To me it seems you can ommit the `out` keyword as you initialize `tourists` already in `Main`. **Note** that `ReadData` only modifies the *content of the list*, not the *reference* to it stored in the `tourists` variable. Since you don't want to change that reference (the *variable's value*), you don't need the `out` keyword.

If you want `ReadData` to initialize it, you need to add the line

```
tourists = new List<Tourist>()
```

in `ReadData` *before* the `foreach` loop.

---

As your code stands, the better solution is to ommit any parameter to `ReadData` and let the method *return* the list instead:

```
static List<Tourist> ReadData()
{
    // create list
    List<Tourist> tourists = new List<Tourist>();

    const string Input = "..\\..\\Duomenys.txt";       

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Input);
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        // shortened for brevity
        tourists.Add(new Tourist(firstName, lastName, money));
    }

    return tourists; // return newly created list
}
```

And use this in `Main` like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Tourist> tourists = ReadData();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Parameters with `out` need to be assigned to in the body of the method and do not get their value carried over from the call site. Quoting [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645764(v=vs.71).aspx):

> Within a method, just like a local variable, an output parameter is initially considered unassigned and must be definitely assigned before its value is used.

In your case there are three ways to solve it:

First, you can move assignment from caller to the method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Tourist> tourists;
    ReadData(out tourists);
}

static void ReadData(out List<Tourist> tourists)
{
    tourists = new List<Tourist>();
    //...
}
```

Second, you can change your declaration to skip `out` in the declaration entirely, which will carry the initiated value to the method and lift the requirement to assign it in that method.

Last option (and the best one IMO, in terms of readability) is to make the list a return value instead of `out` parameter:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Tourist> tourists = ReadData();
}

static List<Tourist> ReadData()
{
    List<Tourist> tourists = new List<Tourist>();
    //...
    return tourists;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a value for your `out`-parameter before leaving the method

```
static void ReadData(out List<Tourist> tourists)
{
    const string Input = "..\\..\\Duomenys.txt";
    tourists = new List<Tourist>();

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Input);
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        string[] values = line.Split(';');
        string firstName = values[0];
        string lastName = values[1];
        double money = Double.Parse(values[2]);
        tourists.Add(new Tourist(firstName, lastName, money));
    }
}
```

However as you´re passing a `List<T>` which is a reference-type you don´t need the `out`.keyword as modifications to the object that you´re referencing are reflected in *all* references.

So after calling `ReadData` the list you´ve provided will change also:

```
var tourists = new List<Tourist>();
ReadData(toursists);  // this changes the elements within the list
// do something with the list
```

Comment: Not in just that case, in every case `out` parameter must be set before method ends.

Comment: @kiziu You´re right, however there are only two execution-paths in this topic: one executing the loop, the other not doing so, thus my comment is true anyway.

Comment: Although it is correct, I think that the first sentence of your answer might be misleading. "In case" might lead to conclusion that if the loop executes, the value for `out` is not required, which is incorrect, because the loop does not initialize the parameter, it only modifies it.